# Melting/Transposing Table help in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking to melt a table, but some of the variables are similarly named and I'm having trouble using the patterns function.

Here is an example of what my data looks like:

| Date | ID | X_a | X_ab | X_c | X_d | Y_a | Y_ab | Y_c | Y_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/18/2022 10:57:17 PM | 001 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

This is how I would like it to look like:

| Date | ID | Group | a | ab | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/18/2022 10:57:17 PM | 001 | X | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3/18/2022 10:57:17 PM | 001 | Y | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

When I use melt, first it has an issue because date is a different type than the remaining variables (character vs. integers) and secondly when I tried without date, the patterns uses "a" and finds additionally ab. Any ideas on how to get this done, either by modifying this method or using a totally different one? It's important to note that this should be something which can be run on large amounts of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
pivot_longer(df, -c(Date, ID), names_to = c('Group', '.value'), names_sep = '_')

# A tibble: 2 x 7
  Date                     ID Group     a    ab     c     d
  <chr>                 <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 3/18/2022 10:57:17 PM     1 X         1     0     0     1
2 3/18/2022 10:57:17 PM     1 Y         1     0     1     2
```